# How to make my private class visible for STD containers?

Tags: c++

This is the code:

```
#include <map>
class Hidden {
private:
  friend class Visible;
  Hidden(); { /* nothing */ }
};
class Visible {
public:
  void f() {
    std::map<int, Hidden> m;
    m[1] = Hidden(); // compilation error, class Hidden is private
  }
};
```

The code doesn't compile because the constructor of class `Hidden` is private for class `std::map`. Obviously, I don't want to make class `std::map` a friend of `Hidden`. But what should I do here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "What are you *doing* here?" is the right question. What is the purpose of the code? And there's no way around it: `map` needs to be able to construct `Hidden`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the map as a friend class:

```
#include <map>
class Hidden {
private:
  friend class Visible;
  friend class std::map<int, Hidden> ;
  Hidden() {}
};
class Visible {
public:
  void f() {
    std::map<int, Hidden> m;
    m[1] = Hidden(); // compilation error, class Hidden is private
  }
};
```

Of course, it means you have to declare all Hidden users inside Hidden, but that's exactly the point of the "private class" pattern you're using...

Comment: @aaa : I did not declare the template map as a friend. Only its instanciation as a map of [int, Hidden]. So There is no problem of portability.

Answer (score 0):

For your class Hidden, map is just another class and unless you explicitly make map a friend of Hidden, it map won't be able to access Hidden's constructor.

The approach given by paercebal must work as he's making map the friend of your class Hidden.